# What is the reason that function is not passed to a Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relaymodern

I'm aware of JavaScript's scopes but probably I don't understand them fully because this code doesn't work.

This code uses React and Relay Modern frameworks.

There are 2 buttons, first one inside `queryRender` which is passed into Relay Modern `QueryRenderer` and second one afterwards (see function `render`). The second one is working, first one doesn't execute the `clickTest` function.
(This is simplified version of actual code)

```
class Candidates extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    viewer: PropTypes.object
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.clickTest = this.clickTest.bind(this)
  }

  clickTest () {
    console.log('click works')
  }    

  queryRender ({error, props}) {
    if (error) {
      return <pre>{error.message}</pre>
    } else if (props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button onClick={this.clickTest}>this DOESN'T work</Button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return <Loader active>Loading...</Loader>
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <QueryRenderer
          environment={environment}
          query={query} 
          render={this.queryRender}
        />
        <Button onClick={this.clickTest}>this works</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `query` variable is defined, I just didn't include it in that excerpt.

When I substitue first button's onClick function with an anonymous one

```
<Button onClick={() => this.clickTest()}>this DOESN'T work</Button>
```

then I get such error: Uncaught TypeError: _this2.clickTest is not a function

Can anyone explain to me why this code behaves the way it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, the meaning of `this` isn't determined when a function is *created*, but rather when it is *invoked*. When QueryRenderer invokes your queryRender function, it doesn't know that it needs to invoke it in the context of your class, so `this` will not be referring to what you think it's referring to.

You'll either need to bind your queryRender function, much like you're doing with your clicktest function in the constructor, or you'll need to redesign queryRender so it doesn't need a reference to `this`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about binding `queryRender` function. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon both Artur and Nicholas' answers, you either need to `bind()` this or use an arrow function to make sure that `this` is referring to the component itself. You already have the bind method down, here's en example of the arrow function which gets rid of the need to bind because arrow functions don't actually bind a this value, they use their parents scope instead...

```
class Candidates extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    viewer: PropTypes.object
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.clickTest = this.clickTest.bind(this)
  }

  clickTest () {
    console.log('click works')
  }    

  queryRender = ({error, props}) => {
    if (error) {
      return <pre>{error.message}</pre>
    } else if (props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button onClick={this.clickTest}>this DOESN'T work</Button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return <Loader active>Loading...</Loader>
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <QueryRenderer
          environment={environment}
          query={query} 
          render={this.queryRender}
        />
        <Button onClick={this.clickTest}>this works</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike S. That's actually very useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function doesn't create new scope and its scope is enclosing execution context, in this case it's `QueryRenderer`  scope where you don't have this function. When you pass it as simple function then the scope will be undefined or not, I don't know what `Button` does inside. I haven't used Rely and not sure you can refer to component from Rely render method.